# Iteration, Recursion, and Multiplication

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to understand what my instructor wants me to do. In his description " Design, implement and test a Java program Multiplication.java which includes an iterative method multIterative and a recursive method multRecursive. Both methods take the same parameters, the two positive integer numbers that will be multiplied and return the multiplication result. For both methods, use the technique of repetitive additions for achieving the multiplication of the two numbers. As an example, 4 multiplied by 6 should be calculated as 6 + 6 + 6 + 6 (i.e. four times six)."

I can understand the multiplication for recursion but not the iterative. Does he want me to make factorials? or what? I need help understanding. Examples would help!

Comment: Might help if you ask the instructor.

Answer (score 1):

A while loop should do the trick

```
public int multiIterative(int firstNum, int secondNum){
    int result;
    while(secondNum > 0){
        result += firstNum;
        secondNum--;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: hmm, that could work but I have something else if too that might work

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but I came up with something like this too. can this work for an Iterative as well?

```
public static int multIterative(int a, int b) {

    if (b == 0) {

        return 1;

    } else if (b < 0) {

        return 0;
    }

    return a * multIterative(a, b - 1);

}
```

Comment: This would be recursive not iterative.

Comment: This is an example of recursion not iteration. Because you're calling multIterative() within itself.

Comment: Also for this recursive function you would probably just want to return a + multiRecursive(a,b-1); or else you will be getting a^n not a*n.

Answer (score 0):

Alright then in recursion for my multRecursion() I did

```
public static int multRecursive(int a, int b) {

    if (a == 0 || b == 0) {

        return 0;
    }

    return multRecursive(a, b - 1) + a;

}
```

Comment: or just go with a + multRecursive (a, b-1)?

Comment: They both should work the same. Looks good @PatrickWilliamMcCully

Comment: also should the return for the if statement be a 1? @Danwakeem

Comment: No because then your recursive function would be off by one if a=6 and b=4 because your recursion would start as 6+1=7 so your second one would be 7+6=13 and so on. @PatrickWilliamMcCully You also don't need the a == 0 in that if statement. It won't hurt anything but it is unnecessary.

Comment: well I am trying to make sure that its only positive numbers

Comment: Oh never mind I was being dumb I see what are saying I am deleting my last comment you should check if a is a positive number. @PatrickWilliamMcCully